# Cannot catch Exception generated în a Task with debug mode

Tags: c#, asynchronous, exception, task

I have following simple test codes:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    try
    {
        Task task = Task.Run(() => { throw null; });
        task.Wait();
    }
    catch (AggregateException ex)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
    }
    Console.ReadKey();
}
```

I expected the exception would be catch and then rethrown by the `task.Wait();`

This works as intended in the `Release` mode, however exception is not catch in the `Debug` mode.

[image: The exception is not catch]

Is that now normal behavior? And Is it possible to change that?

I am using the `Visual Studio 2019 .NET Framework  4.7.2`.
I tried to target older version `.NET Framework 4.5`. It does not changed anything.

Comment: But what is the problem? If you turn off catching unhandled exceptions in VS, you'll see the same result: debugger won't break and the exception details will be output to console.